# Why does this code generate empty space on my website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have [a WordPress website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/about-us/) where I have written the following code,

```
<h3 style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom:25px;margin-top:15px;  text-align: center; font-size: 30px; color: #305f67;"><a id="OurTeam"></a>Our Team</h3>
```

The code works well on another page on the website and on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd66vqcf/) but does not work when I placed it on a new location on the same page. It displays blank space. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: post some CSS code as well.

Comment: If it's working in one place but not another there might be additional CSS rules overriding the inline style. Debug that using your dev tools.

Comment: It's because hide inside another content. Just give `z-index: 2147483647;`  and `position: relative;` to h3 it will display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2835" width="2744" height="790" alt="Complete - NayaJeevanWebsiteDesign" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/pic-1-edit1.jpg" style="margin-top: -140px;">
```

Remove margin-top: -140px; and I am getting Our Team in green color